# Import dynamic array in bash script

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I want to make a number of arrays (successively) available to a function in a script. The data I want to exploit in array form is dynamic and I need to somehow import from a text file with data into a script as the data changes. I deal with the raw data, so my pre-processed data has the form:

```
 1 2 3 32 509.1001
 3.01 43.56 23.5
 1209 898 34.67 0
 etc...
```

In a bash script `myscript.sh`, I tried the following (directly inspired by @choroba's [solutions](http://bash%20how%20to%20pass%20array%20as%20an%20argument%20to%20a%20function)):

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# somehow, import array `testream` here
#
function array_contain(){
    # pass array to script by name
    array_arg=$2[@] 
    loc_array=("${!array_arg}")   # magic here !
    local arr_elt
    for arr_elt in "${loc_array[@]}"; do
        if [ "$arr_elt" == "$1" ]; then
            printf "%d%s\n" "$1" " - yup"; # do something
            exit 0
        fi
    done
    printf "%d%s\n" "$1" " nope"; # do something else
    exit 1
}
array_contain "$1" testream
```

The prbm is this will work only if, when calling `$myscript.sh 34.23 testream`, the array `testream` is known from `myscript.sh`.  In choroba's answer that array is actually assigned a content in the shell if the function is defined and run directly from the interactive shell, or simply defined inside the script.

So, how do I import the array data from a file, place it in the array `testream` so `$myscript.sh 34.23 testream` works ? -- Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to create an array from file content read line by line:

```
readarray -t ARRAY_CREATED_FROM_FILE < <(cat < "/path/to/testream" 2> /dev/null)

for item in "${ARRAY_CREATED_FROM_FILE[@]}"; do
    echo "reading each line. Content: ${item}"
done
```

Maybe this can help you.

Comment: Hello and thank you, but why use: `readarray -t array_to_populate < <(cat < testream)` when the simpler syntax `readarray -t array_to_populate < testream` does the job already ?

Comment: Is the same for you on this case, but maybe useful if you want more complexity, I mean, between parenthesis you can put piped commands for example. `readarray -t array_to_populate < <(cat < testream | grep something)`. Anyway, did it helped you?

Comment: Well, I knew the `mapfile` command... But It is advisable when answering in this forum or anywhere on SE, to *just answer to the OP*. To yr further comment anybody could tell you that: `readarray -t array_to_populate < <(cat < testream | grep something)` can also be achieved more simply with `readarray -t array_to_populate < <( grep -e "something" testream)`. In the absence of context, simple often turns out to be cheaper...